# Ubuntu high memory usage

Tags: 22.04, memory-usage

**Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS**
I just installed Ubuntu Linux today without any programs to install
But 90% of my memory is still full
Do you have any way to help me?

Comment: [Edit] your question with the output of `free -m`. In general, don't worry about RAM use; unused RAM is wasted money.

Comment: Please edit your question and add information how much physical memory your computer has. Stating a relative use of memory only without the reference value is pretty pointless.
Please also state when you experience the 90% use - just after log in with the desktop running but no other programs (like e.g. a web browser) running?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can install `htop` and run it in a shell you should "see" at what is used your memory (I would bet cache)

Comment: OK. But every time I use Linux, 5% is added to my memory, even though I have nothing to do with the installation

Comment: What command do you uses to "see" this memory increase ?

Comment: @Aubuntuuser Don't panic. Read https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ for an explanation for caching